# What exactly does `pod install` do in react-native's autolinking?

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, podfile

I'm using React Native 0.61, and have been reading about the new auto-linking feature. If you have any insight on ANY of the following questions, I'd appreciate it.

**My Questions Are:**

1) My understanding of `react-native link <module>` is that it adds a line for `<module>` to your Podfile, and then you run `pod install`. However, for the last year I've been using `react-native link` and linking manually, and have never run `pod install`. So am I right that `react-native link` does more than just add lines to your Podfile?

2) In the past, when `react-native link` failed to link the module, I manually linked it by dragging the `.xcodeproj` and `.a` files into Xcode as described [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios). Does `react-native link` (when it works) add the line to your Podfile AND add `.xcodeproj` and `.a` files into Xcode for you?

3) Is there anything involved in native modules being linked other than the `.xcodeproj` and `.a` files being added to Xcode?

4) What exactly does `pod install` do? Does it take all the native modules referenced in your Podfile and add `.xcodeproj` and `.a` files into Xcode? If so, that would involve two steps: adding the line to your Podfile and then running `pod install`. Why not just `react-native link`?

5) My understanding of auto-linking is that it adds lines for all native modules to your Podfile, and then you still have to run `pod install`. Isn't this just accomplishing the same thing as `react-native link`?

6) In [this guide](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md) to auto-linking, it says "Autolinking is a replacement for react-native link. If you have been using React Native before version 0.60, please unlink native dependencies if you have any from a previous install.". Why does it tell you to unlink? If the module is already linked, what will unlinking it and re-linking it do? This implies there's a difference between the way modules are linked with `react-native link` and via auto-linking. What happens if you auto-link and then `pod install`, and then try using `react-native link`, or vice versa?

7) I outlined this in the previous questions, but just to make it concise,  *what is the difference between auto-linking + `pod install` and `react-native link`?*

Comment: If you come from a javascript background, think of "pod install" as "npm install" for a cocoapods project, ie. your iOS app. This just installs all of the dependencies that are specified in your xcode project by react-native.

Comment: @HannesHertach Thank you. I do understand conceptually the role of `pod install`. If you have any insight into my specific questions here I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

All of your questions are closely intertwined so I'm going to just give you the details that will hopefully clear up things for you.

> If React Native version <= 0.59 **AND** Cocoapods is **NOT** used in
>   the project :

react-native link will just add the `.xcodeproj` file and the `.a` file to the XCode Project. It will NOT add any lines to the Podfile because in this case, the Podfile doesn't exist.

> If React Native version <= 0.59 **AND** Cocoapods is used in the
>   project :

react-native link will add the lines to the Podfile and install pods. It will NOT add `.xcodeproj` or `.a` file to the XCode Project. This is assuming that the library supports Cocoapods installation. How do you know if the library supports Podfile installation ? They mention it on their Github page/NPM page. Also, such libraries will have a .podspec file as well.
Example :  https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info
See that this library has a `.podspec` file -> RNDeviceInfo.podspec. So this supports Cocoapods installation.
If the library doesn't support Cocoapods installation, react-native link will just add `xcode.proj` and `.a` file to the XCode Project like the above case.

> If React Native version >= 0.61 (Cocoapods is default in this case)

react-native link is NOT required anymore.
You just install the library (`yarn add` or `npm install`)
And then do `pod install`.
What happens here is, Cocoapods grabs the library from the node_modules folder, checks if there is a `.podspec` file and then installs the pods. But it DOESN'T add any lines to the podfile. This is auto-linking that's been introduced in React Native version 0.60.
In case of older libraries that DO NOT have a `.podspec` file, you need to manually link the library by react-native link.

Comment: Ty for this explanation. I trust that what you are saying is correct but is there some documentation you can provide that supports what you are saying? Would like to read more about this.